# How to fix a small page so it displays correctly in IE7? (2)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I've cut a lot of code. The code needed is below. Here is a small html-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML >
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV style="border:1px solid #000;">
    <SPAN style="MARGIN-LEFT:20px;">
        Previous
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FLOAT:right; MARGIN-RIGHT:20px;">
        Next
    </SPAN> 
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

All I want is to display previous and next on the same line. It looks one below another in IE7, but OK in FF and Opera. Chrome was not tested yet. Also, when I remove
 `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">`, 
then Opera displays that two words not in one line as well.
All I want is to display the word "Previous" to the left and "Next" to the right within div and in one line.

What's the best way to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I do not have all of those browsers in front of me at the moment but you could likely clear up the issue by adding `float: left` to the first span. Also, I would assume that some of your other code takes care of this, but for your small sample here are a few additional styles you may need:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML >
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV style="border:1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
    <SPAN style="clear: left; FLOAT:left; MARGIN-LEFT:20px;">
        Previous
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN style="clear: right; FLOAT:right; MARGIN-RIGHT:20px;">
        Next
    </SPAN> 
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Not that we have set a width and overflow value on the containing div. The clear value is not important in most use cases. You can use different width and overflow values (for example, 50% and auto) as appropriate.

For more information and some additional tweaks you may have to make, [see this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). If I had a copy of IE7 handy I would test it out for you but you should be close.

From the article:

> The use of a width or height declaration is required to make the
>   effect work in Explorer Windows and Opera. If you don't include it
>   Explorer Windows continues to show the border at the top of the
>   columns, as if there were no overflow. Opera completely hides the
>   content of the container.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I've just tested it. Now IE7, FF, Opera display both words "Previous" and "Next" out of the div. Now div is not a rectangle, but just a horizontal line above that words.

Comment: @Haradzieniec Add an overflow value (auto or hidden) to your enclosing div

Comment: Thank you. overflow:auto; or overflow:hidden for div helps in FF and Opera, but not in IE7. IE7 displays both words out of div.

Comment: @Haradzieniec I added a few more details on IE7 compatibility for you

Comment: Thank you!!! I followed that article. Added "width:100%;". Works everywhere. Also, you don't need "clear: left;" and "clear: right"; Thank you very much!